# Remove duplicate elements from two sequences

Tags: clojure

I am wondering how to remove duplicate elements from two sequences and combine two sequences. For instance,

```
user=>(remove-dup [1 4 7 10 16] [2 7 18 4])
(1 2 10 18 16)
```

My code is:

```
(defn remove-dup [l1 l2]
  (let [list (concat l1 l2)]
    (loop [l list res '()]
        (if (>= (second (first (frequencies l))) 2) 
            (recur (rest l) res)
            (recur (rest l) (conj res (first (first l))))))))
```

But when I run the code, I got the error message:

```
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:528)
```

How can I fix this code. Thanks!

Comment: Is the order important?

Comment: The order is not important.

Answer (score 6):

Your error is here:

```
(first (first l))
```

Remember, `l` is the sequence of all the elements you haven't handled yet. For instance, in the first iteration of the `loop`, `l` might look like this:

```
(1 4 7 10 16 2 7 18 4)
```

You can see from this that `(first l)` would be `1`, so `(first (first l))` would be trying to treat a number as a sequence, which doesn't work.

If you replace `(first (first l))` with just `(first l)`, you'll get a `NullPointerException` because you don't have a base case: what should you do when `l` is empty? You might do something like this (where `,,,` is a placeholder for your current `if` expression):

```
(if (empty? l)
  res
  ,,,)
```

However, if we try to use the method now, we still don't get the right result:

```
(remove-dup [1 4 7 10 16] [2 7 18 4])
;=> (4 18 7 2 16 10 1)
```

Hrm.

I could try to fiddle with your code some more to get it to work, but there's a better way to solve this problem. Since you're trying to remove duplicates and you don't care about order, the functions in [`clojure.set`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.set) are the right tool for the job here. I would write `remove-dup` like this:

```
(require '[clojure.set :as set])

(defn remove-dup [c1 c2]
  (let [[s1 s2] (map set [c1 c2])]
    (seq (set/difference (set/union s1 s2) (set/intersection s1 s2)))))
```

Example:

```
(remove-dup [1 4 7 10 16] [2 7 18 4])
;=> (1 2 16 10 18)
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I know what my problem is.

Answer (score 2):

there is a number of fatal errors in your code:

The thing that breaks it, is `(first (first l))`, since `l` is the list of numbers, it throws an error when you try to take first item of number.

But there are more important ones:

first of all, even if your code were correct, it doesn't have any case to break the loop, so it would probably lead to the infinite loop (or exception of some kind). Second is your total misunderstanding of the `frequencies` usage. You can't rely on the order of the `frequencies` results, since it returns unordered map (not to mention it is beind called in every loop iteration, which is really bad for preformance).

That's how i would do something like this with a single pass over collections in loop:

```
(defn unique [coll1 coll2]
  (let [items (concat coll1 coll2)]
    (loop [res #{}
           seen #{}
           [x & xs :as items] items]
      (cond ;; if there are no items left to check, returning result
            (empty? items) res
            ;; if we've already seen the first item of a coll, remove it from the resulting set
            (seen x) (recur (disj res x) seen xs)
            ;; otherwise mark it as seen, and add it to the result set
            :else (recur (conj res x) (conj seen x) xs)))))
```

in repl:

```
user> (unique [1 4 7 10 16] [2 7 18 4])
#{1 2 16 10 18}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn remove-dupl [l1 l2]
  (let [rmdup (fn [l1 l2] (remove (set l1) l2))]
    (concat (rmdup l1 l2) (rmdup l2 l1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
(defn remove-dup [l1 l2]
  (let [ls (concat l1 l2)]
    (loop [l (frequencies ls) res '()]
        (if (empty? l) res
            (if (>= (second (first l)) 2) 
                (recur (rest l) res)
                (recur (rest l) (cons (first (first l)) res)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The others have found your errors. I'd like to look at what you are trying to do.

Given that

- the order is not important and
- you are removing duplicate elements

this is the *set operation* [*exclusive or*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) (XOR).

It is not included in [`clojure.set`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.set-api.html). We can either, as [Sam Estep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37105249/1562315) does, define it in terms of the operations we have, or write it more directly ourselves:

```
(defn exclusive-or [sa sb]
  (if (<= (count sa) (count sb))
    (reduce
     (fn [ans a]
       (if (contains? sb a)
         (disj ans a)
         (conj ans a)))
     sb
     sa)
    (recur sb sa)))
```

We can then define

```
(defn remove-dup [xs ys]dited 
  (exclusive-or (set xs) (set ys))
```

For example,

```
(remove-dup [1 4 7 10 16] [2 7 18 4]) ;#{1 2 10 16 18}
```

---

Edited to correct error in `exclusive-or`.